# Transform a list of customers and products into a matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix

I recently started reading about product recommendation. Basically I would like to build a small recommendation engine using python. My problem is that I have three lists:

1. List of all customers
2. List of all products
3. List of all orders

The list of orders is actually a 2D array containing customer's ID and product's ID.

What I would like to do is to create a Boolean matrix with customer's ID as rows and product's ID as columns and then fill it up. 1 if the customer has bought the product and 0 if customer didn't buy it.

Let me know if I wasn't clear. Help will be much appreciated. Thanks a lot.

[image: example matrix]

Comment: So your question is on how to fill an 2d array in python?

Comment: @PinkieSwirl no it is how to build a matrix (length of customers, length of products). I am not able to illustrate this in the comment.. what i want is to see a matrix with customers ID as rows and product ids as columns. After that I would like to cross check customers ID with Products ID and put a 1 if the customer has bought this product and a 0 if not.

Comment: Then add illustrate it in your answer, you can edit it.

Comment: @PinkieSwirl Done. I attached a picture

Comment: So you want to print it in such a table form?

Comment: yes, do you think it is hard to do? Thanks

Comment: Do you want to print it as text in a console or in a GUI? And you should show what you tried yet (code, etc..). I'm not using python myself, so I can't actually answer your question, but at least it should be in such a form that someone who can python should be able to answer it :)

Comment: @PinkieSwirl thanks a lot for the advice. To be honest, I still didn't write any code since I didn't choose the algorithm I want to use for the recommendation. I only imported a list of customers, products and orders. In order to find similarities between different customers I need to construct this matrix as an initial step but I am blocked!

Comment: Just show what you got so far, so that one can see how your code structure is. Is customers a list of string literals or ids? Same for products etc... Are those list a global field or do you read them in from a file/user input? If you have absolutely nothing, then you might not get any answers, since that's not what stackoverlow is for 'here my problem and data solve it'. Try to be as specific as possible. As you see I had quite a hard time to understand what you actually want.